# YUv- File to YUV- Images with Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to split a yuv- Sequence into its single Images with this shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Input Parameter: YUV-Sequenz
FILESIZE=22118400 # size of a single image
NUMIM=10 # number of images in input file
for i in `seq 0 $(($NUMIM-1))`
do   
  dd if=$1 skip=$((i*FILESIZE)) bs=$FILESIZE count=1 of=$1.frame$i.yuv
done
```

I always get this error:

```
dd: invalid number ‘’
```

Can u tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running loop with `echo` and see if it looks correct:

```bash
FILESIZE=22118400
NUMIM=10
for i in `seq 0 $(($NUMIM-1))`; do
    echo "dd if=$1 skip=$((i*FILESIZE)) bs=$FILESIZE count=1 of=$1.frame$i.yuv"
done
```

Will print:

```
dd if= skip=0 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame0.yuv
dd if= skip=22118400 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame1.yuv
dd if= skip=44236800 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame2.yuv
dd if= skip=66355200 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame3.yuv
dd if= skip=88473600 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame4.yuv
dd if= skip=110592000 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame5.yuv
dd if= skip=132710400 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame6.yuv
dd if= skip=154828800 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame7.yuv
dd if= skip=176947200 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame8.yuv
dd if= skip=199065600 bs=22118400 count=1 of=.frame9.yuv
```

That doesn't look correct. Did you mean `$i` not `$1`?

Comment: Yes $1 was a mistake. With echo I get the same output as you, but It doesn't seem to create these yuv-Files